# Android app programming different from game programming?

Tags: android

I'm making a business application but I've been following the tutorial of Beginning Android Games by Mario Zechner (I intended to make a game first).

In Mario's tutorial he uses one activity for the entire app, and doesn't really use the xml layouts. He also uses the assetmanager directly instead of the Resource object and created his own render thread.

What are some key differences between developing a business app and game app programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use xml layout and use the resource files. Essentially follow the Android way.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing app tools but then i started moving into gaming. I tried to keep usong the same concepts and it was too tough. You are limited by Animations capability. 
Theen i found out that you probably need to use surface view to be your rendering space so you can move stuffs around and make graphics interact. You can still create it with xml but the actual interaction is done programmativally

Then I recently discovered something. There are android gaming engines out there (just googlr them) thay makes gaming.much simplier and more efficient. I advise you to start with normal android way for your business app then move to gaming engine for gaming app as it is based on android basic knowledge
Good luck